# YouTubeProfile->getUsername() returns gibberish

Tags: youtube-api

We are still using the V2 YouTube API.  After authorizing a user, I have the following code.

```
$token = Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token'], $client->getHttpClient());
$youTubeService = $this->Youtube->_getClient($token);
$profile = $youTubeService->getUserProfile('default');
$username = $profile->getUsername()->getText();
```

However this is not returning a valid username.  It returns a string of gibberish such as "HV1lXoWFbpKgumhGZxurEg"

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the users actual username?  I need it in order to determine the users Channel URL.  Adding the username returned to the following URL gives an error of Invalid Username

http://www.youtube.com/profile_videos?user=HV1lXoWFbpKgumhGZxurEg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every account has a unique username, you should not depend on usernames but instead on channel ids.

From [API documents](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids):

The biggest takeaway for developers using the older Data API v2 is that you must be aware that not every YouTube channel has a unique username. Fortunately, every YouTube channel is guaranteed to have a unique channel ID associated with it, represented by the value in the `<yt:channelId>` tag, and that’s the value that we recommend developers use instead of usernames. For instance, if you have a database that maps YouTube usernames to information about that channel, your older entries should continue to work. (Existing channels won’t lose their usernames.) However, as time goes on, it will become more and more likely that you’ll have to work with channels that can’t be uniquely identified by a username.

A couple of factors simplify the transition from usernames to channel IDs. First, the Data API v2 accepts channel IDs in request URLs wherever it accepts YouTube usernames, meaning that you can seamlessly swap a channel ID into your existing code. For example, since UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw is the channel ID for the channel with the legacy username GoogleDevelopers, the following two URLs are equivalent API requests:

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoogleDevelopers?v=2.1`
`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw?v=2.1`

Another thing to keep in mind is that whenever you’re making authenticated v2 requests, you never need to include the authorized channel’s username when constructing request URLs. You can always use the value default in place of a username (or channel ID). So if you want to retrieve the video uploads feed for the currently authorized user, for instance, you can do so at https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads?v=2.1.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  So it sounds like what is being returned from the getUsername() call is the Channel ID? If so, is there any way to determine the channel's URL from this value?

Comment: I think I figured it out myself.  It seems that prepending the Channel ID with Actually, youtube.com/channel/UC loads the correct channel.  Thanks for your help!